# ¿Por qué CKEditor rompe el formato si no se copia hasta el simbolo de fin de parrafo?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ckeditor

Al copiar un texto desde Word sin incluir el símbolo de fin de párrafo, el texto se desordena.
Adjunto imágenes de ejemplo.
[image: El texto de referencia] 
[image: Como lo está mostrando]
[image: Como es mi resultado esperado]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el formato de archivo docx, el formato se puede aplicar a elementos de distinta naturaleza. Si el formato está aplicado al párrafo pero no incluyes el caracter que delimita el párrafo, el editor de texto aplicará el formato de párrafo predeterminado en lugar del formato de párrafo del documento de origen.

Tal vez te resulte útil leer [Información general acerca del modelo de objetos de Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/kw65a0we.aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias!